# My homebrew is completely broken, how do i start from scratch with new install

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew

My homebrew is completely broken and will not uninstall. I can no longer use the brew command and i cannot reinstall it because it thinks homebrew still exist. How do I remove any trace homebrew was ever on my machine so I can start from scratch?

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223

Comment: I am not sure if this works or not because homebrew still will not reinstall due to a not being able unlink old library files.Here is an example error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Aliases/0mq' (Permission denied)

Comment: Well try it and see - if it fails then manually delete any problem links or files.

Comment: I did a search on my machine and I have no Library/Aliases,Library/Contributions, and no Library/ENV. I also do not have a homebrew folder but the install still gives me a unable to unlink old files in the three folders i listed above. I even emptied my trash just in case it was trying to reference something in there. After it fails install if I try to reinstall, it tells me to put in the following command, rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup. When I put that command in I get the following errors

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/brew: line 13: cd: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/../Library: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/brew: line 23: /brew.rb: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/brew: line 23: exec: /brew.rb: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Comment: This is covered in the Homebrew FAQ: [How do I uninstall Homebrew?](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew)

Answer (score -1):

I don't care to try the following on my machine, because I quite like my `Homebrew` installation, but I think it will pretty much blow all of your broken installation away...

I would suggest you leave it for a while and see if any other bright sparks on SO have a better idea, or any comments, then make a backup of your system on TimeMachine and have at it!

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew  # remove personal caches
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew    # remove personal logs


sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew                    # remove system-wide caches
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Library        # trash all homebrew stuff
```

Comment: Whoa, there's a _lot_ more in /usr/local than just Homebrew stuff. Pretty sure you want /usr/local/Cellar

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ok, thank you. I will be more specific and maybe you can have another look in a bit, please. Comments welcome!

Comment: OTHER STUFF MIGHT BE INSTALLED in the bin, sbin, etc, opt directories. You shouldn't indiscriminately blow them away like this. /usr/local and its subdirectories are not Homebrew's exclusive property.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ok, thank you for your thoughts. I have become a lot more specific and targeted now. Let's hope it removes enough to get the OP re-started.